# How to import opencv in python (not from virtualenv) [UBUNTU]

Tags: python, opencv, import

I have problem about importing OpenCV to my project.
Not actually problem, but I didn't find how to do that. I know it's trivial, but I really don't know.

I have opencv downloaded and compiled in my home directory.
I know how to import it in virtualenv, but how to import it directly from original - non virtualenv python2.7?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the virtualenv?

Answer (score 0):

To import opencv in your python project `import cv2`